# WCF Service return conditional object type

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, datamember

I have this controller

```
public ActionResult Retrieve()
{
   ServiceResponse resp = service.GetModel();
   if(resp.model == null)
   {
      return Json(resp.model);
   }

   return Json(new { Messages = resp.Messages, Data = respmodel, Stream = resp.Stream});
}
```

I want to remove conditional json in controller so controller just return like this

```
public ActionResult Retrieve()
{
   ServiceResponse resp = service.GetModel();
   return Json(resp.Result);
}
```

But `MyModel` and `new { Messages = resp.Messages, Data = respmodel, Stream = resp.Stream}` is different type of object. I want to declare it as 1 data member.

I already try this

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
   [DataMember]
   public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

But it gives me an error. I think I can't use `object` in `DataContract`. I also tried to add `[KnownType(MyModel)]`. 
But it doesn't work.

Comment: why not change the type of result to ServiceResponse? Like this `public ServiceResponse Result { get; set; }`

Comment: @Sherlock If I change it like you mentioned above, I can't assign value in my service method. Because it will be a different type between the `result` and value that I'm going to return to controller. The reason why I'm using an `object` is so I can return every kind of object type. But it getting error when I try to run it.